# Server side react-router won't render my routes

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, react-router

I'm with version 1.0.0-rc1 and my match function won't render my route correctly.

This is my server

```
import express from 'express';
import React from 'react';
import createLocation from 'history/lib/createLocation'
import Router, { match, RoutingContext } from 'react-router';
import createRoutes from './create-routes';

const app = express();
const routes = createRoutes();

app.use((req, res) => {
  let location = createLocation(req.url);

  match({ routes, location }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (redirectLocation)
      res.status(301).redirect(redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
    else if (error)
      res.status(500).send(error.message)
    else if (renderProps == null)
      res.status(404).send('Not found')
    else
      res.send(React.renderToString(<RoutingContext {...renderProps}/>))
  });
});

export default app;
```

This is my routes

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import Application from './components/Application.react';
import Home from './components/Home.react';

export default function() {
  return (
    <Route path="/" component={Application}>
      <Route path="home" component={Home} />
    </Route>
  );
}
```

What do i do wrong in this? When i ask for /home, it should render `<h1>Home</h1>` instead of `<h1>Application</h1>`. Just simple as that.

I based this on this https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/advanced/ServerRendering.md

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using subroutes. This means, that when you go to "/home" first Application is rendered, then the child Home is injected and available via `this.props.children` inside of the Application Component.
See [here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/RouteConfiguration.md) for a simple example:

Try this (not nested):

```
<Route path="/" component={Application}>
<Route path="/home" component={Home} />
```

If you want to render your Application component around the Home component use

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Application</h1>
            { this.props.children }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Edited the render for the Application component in :)

Comment: See question tho, how would you render childRoutes then serverside?