# ReactRouter.match has no callback arguments when attempting to server-render react elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, server-rendering

I've tried following [this guide](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ServerRendering.md) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789537/server-side-react-router-wont-render-my-routes), but am getting undefined for all callback arguments when `ReactRouter.match` is fired.

This is my server:

```
var app = new (require('express'))()
var port = 3000

var ReactDomServer = require('react-dom/server');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var routes = require('./es6/routes.js');

app.use(function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.url);
    ReactRouter.match({ routes: routes, location: req.url }, function(error, redirectLocation, renderProps) {
        console.log('error', error); // undefined
        console.log('erredirectLocationror', redirectLocation); // undefined
        console.log('renderProps', renderProps); // undefined
    });
})

app.listen(port, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error)
  } else {
    console.info("==> Listening on port %s. Open up http://localhost:%s/ in your browser.", port, port)
  }
})
```

like the comments show, `error`, `redirectLocation`, and `renderProps` all log as `undefined`.

Logging the `routes` variable kicks off:

```
{ default: 
   { '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
     type: 
      { [Function]
        displayName: 'Route',
        createRouteFromReactElement: [Function: createRouteFromReactElement],
        propTypes: [Object] },
     key: null,
     ref: null,
     props: { path: '/', component: [Function: App], children: [Object] },
     _owner: null,
     _store: {} } }
```

It starts as a typescript file, **routes.tsx**:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router'
import App from './containers/app';
import Home from './containers/home';

export default (
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
        <Route path='/home' component={Home} />
    </Route>
)
```

which compiles to **es6/routes.js**

```
"use strict";
const React = require('react');
const react_router_1 = require('react-router');
const app_1 = require('./containers/app');
const home_1 = require('./containers/home');
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.default = (React.createElement(react_router_1.Route, {path: '/', component: app_1.default}, React.createElement(react_router_1.Route, {path: '/home', component: home_1.default})));
//# sourceMappingURL=routes.js.map
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `undefined` values because nothing is matching, it's 404ing.

The reason that nothing is matching is because you are mixing es5 and es6 modules.  Try passing `routes.default` into match().